# Exporting data from Sybase to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, sybase, export-to-excel

I have been successful exporting the data to CSV, but now the user wants it to be in an Excel sheet without having to import using CSV. I figured out how to create the headers, but now need to iterate through about 44,000 rows of data placing it in Excel. I looked on here for a answer I could use, but didn't find anything **yet**, that was useful for what I need to do.

I already have my DB connection, just not sure how to write the loop to export to excel.

Comment: You should be searching how to create/write an excel workbook from C#, since that's essentially what you need to do.

Comment: I've tried, but the answers I've found are all writing names and numbers manually. I need to loop through 44,000 rows of with 11 columns of data.

Comment: So, that's how you'll do it.  I don't believe that there's any silver bullet single-method API for doing what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: The data changes on a monthly basis, there's gotta be a way to do it, I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: Which Sybase RDBMS product are you using (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage)?  If using SQLAnywhere/IQ, see [exporting data to excel](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbusage/load-s-4183756-sql.html) for a SQL query example that generates a *.xls file